# How to open another window in SwiftUI, macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'd like to show a second window with different content in a SwiftUI app on macOS. I can't find any documentation on this. The attempt below doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showSecondWindow: Bool = false
}

@main
struct MultipleWindowsApp: App {
    @StateObject var appState = AppState()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(appState)
        }
        WindowGroup {
            if appState.showSecondWindow {
                SecondContent()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button("Open 2nd Window") {
                appState.showSecondWindow = true
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct SecondContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, from window #2.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Here's an extension for creating a window for `NSViewController`, assigning a title and opening it.

```
extension View {
    
    @discardableResult
    func openInWindow(title: String, sender: Any?) -> NSWindow {
        let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: self)
        let win = NSWindow(contentViewController: controller)
        win.contentViewController = controller
        win.title = title
        win.makeKeyAndOrderFront(sender)
        return win
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Button("Open 2nd Window") {
    SecondContent().openInWindow(title: "Win View", sender: self)
}
```

To close the window

```
NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.close()
```

Comment: Use this to programmatically close the window: `NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.close()`

Comment: I tried this in Xcode 14, and I'm not getting any errors, but nothing happens when the button is clicked either

Comment: When you get to this line `win.makeKeyAndOrderFront(sender)`, it should work as any other `NSWIndow`, since it _is_ `NSWindow`.. Can you open any window? Maybe not SwiftUI related? You can try to access the `contantViewController` from the window and check it.

Comment: This opens the window with a zero size. So you can't see it and neet to resize it.

Answer (score 16):

**Tested on Xcode 13 beta, SwiftUI 3.0**

After having being in this situation, I Frankensteined some answers that where all over the internet and this works for me:

On the @main (MyAppApp) file add the amount of `WindowGroup("Window Name")` you need:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        
        WindowGroup("Second Window") {
            SecondWindow()
        }.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "SecondWindow"))
        
        WindowGroup("Third Window") {
            ThirdWindow()
        }.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "ThirdWindow"))

}
```

What to place in every `WindowGroup`?:

```swift
WindowGroup("SecondWindow") /*Any name you want to be displayed at the top of the window.*/ {
            SecondWindow() //View you want to display.
}.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "SecondWindow")) //Name of the view without ().
```

Now, at the end of the MyAppApp file (outside of the `struct MyAppApp: App`) add the following `enum` :

```swift
enum OpenWindows: String, CaseIterable {
    case SecondView = "SecondView"
    case ThirdView   = "ThirdView"
    //As many views as you need.

    func open(){
        if let url = URL(string: "myapp://\(self.rawValue)") { //replace myapp with your app's name
            NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following to your `Info.plist`

[image: Info.plist]

Replace myapp with your app's name.

*Usage*:

```swift
Button(action: {
            OpenWindows.SecondView.open()
       }){
            Text("Open Second Window")           
         }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the `Settings` scene? `handlesExternalEvents` shows an error saying that it is only available for WindowGroups

Comment: Why are you using `Set(arrayLiteral:)`? It's very bizarre; that method is meant to be called only by the compiler.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t work on macOS 13 Beta 1.

Comment: I have tried this in Xcode 13.4.1 and all it does is open the main ContentView from the first window each time. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Update June 2022: windowing APIs have now been added. I'll leave old answer below as it might still be useful for those that need external linking.

The method you are looking for is `WindowGroup` and `View`'s `handlesExternalEvents`. You also need to first create a URL scheme to identify your book, add it to your Info.plist. When calling `@Environment`'s `openURL`, if a View with `handlesExternalEvents` that matches the book's URL is already in a window then it'll re-activate that window. Otherwise it will use the `handlesExternalEvents` applied to the `WindowGroup` to open a new window.

You can see a sample on my blog [here](https://www.malcolmhall.com/2020/12/06/open-window-scene-in-swiftui-2-0-on-macos/).

Comment: Yay, the code in the blog worked for me. I was looking for a solution like this. Thanks.

Comment: @malhal I get that you want to growth-hack your blog. But now the link is broken and the answer is gone...

Comment: lol fixed now, but you should use the new window APIs

Answer (score 3):

Regarding official [WWDC guide](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10061/) the solution is using `Window` class and
`@Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow`

Scheme isn't a proper solution

For example,

```
var body: some Scene {
        Window("FirstView", id: "FirstView") {
            FirstView(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
        Window("SecondView", id: "SecondView") {
            SecondView(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
```

To open `SecondView` from `FirstView`:

```
struct FirstView: View {
@Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow

var body: some View {
// code code
// tap handler
openWindow(id: "SecondView")
}
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

This will open a new window:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        Button(action: {openMyWindow()},
               label: {Image(systemName: "paperplane")})
            .padding()
    }
}

func openMyWindow()
{
    var windowRef:NSWindow
    windowRef = NSWindow(
        contentRect: NSRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 600),
        styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
        backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    windowRef.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: WindowView())
    windowRef.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}

struct WindowView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        Text("Hello World")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the old way before SwiftUI 2.0.

Comment: If this is the "old" way, could you add the "new" way?

Comment: If the 'new' way is using custom URL scheme, that's a horrible way to create a new window. It means you need to 'hard code' every window into the `info.plist` file. It just feels wrong in every way. I rather just use `NSHostingView` than add windows to the `info.plist`.

Comment: No need for 'hard code' every window in the `info.plist`.
`URL Scheme` is enough.

Comment: When I close a window that was created like that, the app crashes in @main, do we know why?

Comment: This doesn't doing anything in Xcode 14

Answer (score 2):

In macOS 13, you can now [register](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup/init(for:content:)) and [open](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/openwindow) windows programmatically:

```swift
@main
struct OpenWindowApp: App {
    @StateObject private var dataStore = DataStore()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(dataStore)
        }
        WindowGroup("Note", for: Note.ID.self) { $noteId in
            NoteView(noteId: noteId)
                .environmentObject(dataStore)
        }
    }
}
```

(from [source](https://nilcoalescing.com/blog/ProgrammaticallyOpenANewWindowInSwiftUIOnMacOS/)).

I had some fun recreating it in macOS 11:

```swift
import SwiftUI

private class WindowStorage {

    static let main = WindowStorage()

    private var blocks: [ObjectIdentifier: (AnyHashable) -> AnyView] = [:]

    func viewContent<E: Hashable>(for element: E) -> AnyView? {
        let type = ObjectIdentifier(E.self)
        guard let view = blocks[type]?(element) else { return nil }
        return view
    }

    func registerContent<E: Hashable, V: View>(block: @escaping (E) -> V) {
        let type = ObjectIdentifier(E.self)
        return blocks[type] = { anyHash in
            guard let element = anyHash as? E else { return AnyView(EmptyView()) }
            return AnyView(block(element))
        }
    }
}

extension View {

    func openWindow<E: Hashable>(_ element: E) {
        guard let view = WindowStorage.main.viewContent(for: element) else { return }
        let root = NSHostingController(rootView: view)
        let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: root)
        window.toolbar = NSToolbar()
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.windowController?.showWindow(window)
    }
}
extension WindowGroup {

    init<E: Hashable, C: View>(for element: E.Type,
                               content: @escaping (E) -> C) where Content == WindowWrappingView {
        self.init {
            WindowWrappingView()
        }
        WindowStorage.main.registerContent(block: content)
    }
}

struct WindowWrappingView: View {

    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

It is terrible. Specially the usage of the `NSHostingController` breaks things, like the `toolbar` modifier.

If you are looking for some backward solution, it can still help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick gist [View+NSWindow.swift](https://gist.github.com/kdeda/d7c2f6aafc066793e8cc8f4e398d0814)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            ChildView().openInNewWindow { window in
                window.title = "Window title"
            }
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "paperplane")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Hello World")
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 640, minHeight: 480)
    }
}
```